# Copy Compiled DLLs To Source Control In Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need to setup a build pipeline in VSTS to deploy a web service. The web service has a reference to another visual studio solution. I can copy over the compiled dll to the web service solution that is getting published before checking in, but I would like to create a build pipeline to build the referenced solution and copy the compiled dlls to the solution that will be built and deployed to an Azure Web App.

Is this possible?

I tried using "Copy Files" task, but I couldn't figure out how to copy from the built folder.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this feature is not feasible.The solution built by the Visual Studio build task is from repo or msbuild project.If you want to copy the dlls to the solution, you can only copy it to the repo. Even if the dlls are passed by other means, the build solution is still obtained from the repo.
[image]

You can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution for this type of scenario is to set up a build pipeline that publishes artifacts (compiled dlls) to the Azure Artifacts (either NuGet package or Universal Package/ZipArchive). Then in the CI of the target project, consume the artifact by getting package from Azure Artifact.  You can set up auto publish for dependency based on triggers to make sure when changes are introduced in the dependent solution will re-publish a new version.

I do not want to recommend a hack where in the yaml pipeline you get from source the dependent solution and utilize relative path patching in csproj of the target solution to recompile everything. It's ugly and promotes coupling.